# VBA button that adds a data point to a series on a graph?

Tags: vba, excel

In my report I have a graph that is updated every month.  It only has one series of data on it and adds a new point to that series every month.  This is a small part of a larger code that gets the report together.  I'm sorry in advance for how choppy it is.  The "XXX" Is a placeholder column, so that I can reference a dynamic location.  I will typically `.Offset` from "XXX" to various locations around the Worksheet.

this section `Autofills` the next date into a column that is to the left of the placeholder.  It is the X coordinate of my Graph.

```
Dim Dates As Range
Dim StartDate As Range
Dim EmptyDateCell As Range
Dim LastDateCell As Range
Dim AllDateCells As Range

    Set StartDate = ws.Rows("3").Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -3)
    Set LastDateCell = ws.Rows("3").Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -2)
    Set EmptyDateCell = ws.Rows("3").Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -1)
    Set Dates = ws.Range(StartDate.Address & ":" & LastDateCell.Address)
    Set AllDateCells = ws.Range(Dates.Address & ":" & EmptyDateCell.Address)

Dates.AutoFill Destination:=AllDateCells
```

This is my range of Y coordinates.  It is also added to every month, Via `Autofill`.

```
Dim Averages As Range
Dim StartAverage As Range
Dim EmptyAverageCell As Range
Dim LastAverageCell As Range
Dim AllAverageCells As Range

    Set StartAverage = ws.Rows("171").Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -3)
    Set LastAverageCell = ws.Rows("171").Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -2)
    Set EmptyAverageCell = ws.Rows("171").Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(0, -1)
    Set Averages = ws.Range(StartAverage.Address & ":" & LastAverageCell.Address)
    Set AllAverageCells = ws.Range(Averages.Address & ":" & EmptyAverageCell.Address)

Averages.AutoFill Destination:=AllAverageCells
```

This is the dynamic location of both my X and Y coordinates.  It sets up a `Range` that goes from a cell to a dynamic cell that is `Offset` from the placeholder.

```
Dim rng171 As Range
Dim rng188 As Range
Dim xoffset As Range

    Set xoffset = ws.Rows("171").Cells.Find("XXX").Offset(-17, 0)
    Set rng171 = ws.Range("D171")
    Set rng188 = ws.Range("D188")
```

This is the part of the code that fails.  I'm trying to add the x and y coordinates to the chart that is already made and is sitting in the Worksheet

```
Charts("Cpk Average").SeriesCollection("Cpk").Values = ws.Range(rng171.Address & ":" & EmptyAverageCell.Address)
Charts("Cpk Average").SeriesCollection("Cpk").XValues = ws.Range(rng188.Address & ":" & xoffset.Address)
```

It says the `script is out of range`.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Any questions let me know.

Here is an example of what my project looks like.  This is not what my code above is for.  It is just to help visualize the process.  This example will be at the exact point in the code before adding data to the graph.  Take a look at the comments on the example.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Cnpvgoos3caVNJUUgxbVNGeHM

Thanks

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: `Charts("Cpk Average").SeriesCollection("Cpk").Values = ws.Range(rng171.Address & ":" & EmptyAverageCell.Address)`

Comment: That would suggest that `"Cpk Average"` is not a named chart, or if it is, then `"Cpk"` is not a named series in that chart. Try evaluating those parts in the Immediate window & see which raises the error.

Comment: How exactly Should I go about evaluating them? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In the VBE, from View menu, ensure that you have the "Immediate" pane enabled. Then, do: `?Charts("Cpk Average").Name` and see if that raises an error? If not, then do `?Charts("Cpk Average").SeriesCollection("Cpk").Name` and see what happens. If both of those are valid, it should print out the respective `.Name` properties.

Comment: Also, ensure the chart is on the ActiveSheet, otherwise you need to qualify it specifically to its parent sheet.

Comment: Does `EmptyAverageCell` have any value or is it empty? You're doing a Find do fill that Range - what if it doesn't find anything?

Comment: It fails at `?Charts("Cpk Average").Name`  I think I'm not referencing my chart correctly.  `EmptyAverageCell` Has a value.

Comment: I think my Chart is defined as `ChartObjects("chart 10")` .  when I put that in followed by `.Name` it gives me `Chart 10`.   Now I think all I have to do is get the name of the series correct.

Comment: I got my series right now, but now `EmptyAverageCell` is now equal to nothing.  @dbmitch      The line now reads `ws.ChartObjects("chart 10").Chart.SeriesCollection("series1").Values = ws.Range(rng171.Address & ":" & EmptyAverageCell.Address)`

Comment: @dbmitch see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it.  The last two lines of code are as follows

```
ws.ChartObjects("chart 10").Chart.SeriesCollection("series1").Values = ws.Range(rng171.Address & ":" & EmptyAverageCell.Address)

ws.ChartObjects("chart 10").Chart.SeriesCollection("series1").XValues = ws.Range(rng188.Address & ":" & xoffset.Address)
```

The code needs to have the `.ChartObjects` because the chart is in a sheet , and does not have it's own sheet.  Both my series and chart names were wrong, and I was missing the `.Chart`which is a property, not an object, if I understand this correctly. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.